# Getting junk character while sending encrypted json request to webservice via resttemplate

Tags: encryption

Requirement : Need to send the encrypted json request to the webservice and service will send the decrypted result back to the client.

Issue : We are using Spring RestTemplate. While sending the encrypted data we are sending junk character to webservice so in webservice we are getting below error.

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/SpringBootRestApi] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.exceptions.Base64DecodingException: You must initialize the xml-security library correctly before you use it. Call the static method "com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.Init.init();" to do that before you use any functionality from that library.] with root cause